# How to check test coverage percentage in Github Actions

Tags: jestjs, github-actions

I have a react project published to GitHub, and trying to set up GitHub Actions.

I want to add one step to check if the unit test coverage passes 65% (have to pass it to go through CI/CD process successfully).

This is what I've tried:

```yaml
build:
    name: Test
    steps:
      - name: Coverage
        run: npm run jest-coverage
```

I need help on following items:

- How can I check if the coverage percentage passes 65%?
- How to make the process fail if the coverage is lower than 65%?
- How can I make it rerun it whenever there's a new commit pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming that your npm script `jest-coverage` runs jest with coverage enabled*

Requiring 65% test coverage can be achieved with the jest configuration [coverageThreshold](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragethreshold-object).

Add this to your `jest.config.js`:

```js
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 65,
        "functions": 65,
        "lines": 65,
        "statements": 65
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for re-running your job when new code is pushed, you want to trigger your workflow on `push`, like so:

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  ...
```

Depending on how you're working with branches and pull requests, the `push` could also be replaced with `pull_request`.

Comment: Does this fail the build for you? It doesn't for me, but not sure if it's because I have two jest projects in my jest.config